# Getting current directory in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, directory

I'm trying to get the current directory and use it to run an application no matter where the file is put and no matter how the path is changed

```
Dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim CurrentDirectory
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Dim Directory
Directory = CurrentDirectory\attribute.exe

Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "Directory" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

How do I actually set up this code so it does what I want it to do correctly?

Comment: The 2 simplest ways: 
(1) Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "") 
(2) Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))

Answer (score 60):

You should use **WScript.ScriptFullName** which returns the full path of the *executing script*.

`WScript.Echo( WScript.ScriptFullName )` will give output like :  `c:\myscripts\cool.vbs`

You can get the parent path `c:\myscripts`, by using String manipulation or  fso.GetParentFolderName(path) - Both methods are safe and will return the desired result.

---

VBScript

- using string manipulation:

```vb
' VBscript string manipulation
scriptDir = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\") - 1)
```

- or using FileSystemObject

```vb
' VBscript FileSystemObject
scriptDir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

---

JScript versions:

```js
// JScript string manipulation
var scriptdir = WScript.ScriptFullName.substring(0,WScript.ScriptFullName.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

```js
// JScript using FileSystemObject
var scriptDir = new ActiveXObject(("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

---

That's all you need ;)

---

**Dont't use fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")** or **wShell.CurrentDirectory** ( unless you really intend to )

The problem using those is that they both return the current `working directory` which will work fine if you just doubleclick the file, but if the file is called from some other location, then the working directory will most likely be something else than the script location.

If you do this in console:

```
C:\Users>cscript //nologo "C:\myscripts\cool.vbs"
```

Then your working directory will be `C:\Users`, not `C:\myscripts`

If you drop a file onto your vbs file (launcing the script in WScript with arguments), then the working dir will be `C:\Windows\System32` (!) (even if the dropped file is in the same directory as the vbs script.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: The first example need a minor correction:
WScript.ScriptFullName.substring(0,WScript.ScriptFullName.lastIndexOf(WScript.ScriptName) - 1)

Comment: Simplest in VBScript:
 WScript.Echo Mid(WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, (Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName)))

Comment: Since OP asked about VBScript, I would like to caution readers on Jakob's first code line, which is an _JScript_ example. It will **not** work in VBScript, as .substring is a method to an object, but WScript.FullScriptName is just a literal string in VBScript and not an object. @ndemarco's comment right above mine works well.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property.

```
Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
WshShell.Run strCurDir & "\attribute.exe", 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Note: This returns the directory from where the script was executed, not necesarily the directory of the script itself.

Comment: For an example, if you drag drop a file onto a batfile which runs the script, then the workingdir will be the directory of that file.

Answer (score 26):

Your problem is not getting the directory (`fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")` resolves the current working directory just fine). Even if you wanted the script directory instead of the current working directory, you could easily determine that as Jakob Sternberg described in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225466/1630171).

What does not work in your code is building a path from the directory and your executable. This is invalid syntax:

> ```
> Directory = CurrentDirectory\attribute.exe
> ```

If you want to build a path from a variable and a file name, the file name must be specified as a string (or a variable containing a string) and either concatenated with the variable directory variable:

```
Directory = CurrentDirectory & "\attribute.exe"
```

or (better) you construct the path using the [BuildPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt) method:

```
Directory = fso.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, "attribute.exe")
```

Comment: didnt even know you could get down votes but i didnt put it there

Comment: This property is not set in my scripts.

Comment: @sirdank I have no idea what property you're talking about, since there isn't any mentioned in my answer. Care to explain?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I apologize, I am an idiot. I see now from more careful examination of the question that you are not suggesting `CurrentDirectory` is a global property holding the CWD but that OP is incorrectly constructing his path. I got confused by skimming the question and the answer below. I'll continue trying to retract my downvote but for right now it says my vote is locked.

Comment: Once a vote is locked you can't retract it until the answer is edited again. Please make sure you fully understand an answer before casting a vote on it from now on.

Answer (score 8):

```
'-----Implementation of VB6 App object in VBScript-----
Class clsApplication
    Property Get Path()
          Dim sTmp
          If IsObject(Server) Then
               'Classic ASP
               Path = Server.MapPath("../")
          ElseIf IsObject(WScript) Then 
               'Windows Scripting Host
               Path = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStr(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName) - 2)
          ElseIf IsObject(window) Then
               'Internet Explorer HTML Application (HTA)
               sTmp = Replace( Replace(Unescape(window.location), "file:///", "") ,"/", "\")
               Path = Left(sTmp, InstrRev( sTmp , "\") - 1)
          End If
    End Property
End Class
Dim App : Set App = New clsApplication 'use as App.Path
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've done. (Give a man a fish -- feed him for a day, teach a man to fish -- feed him for a lifetime.)

Comment: VBScript gets used in several different environments (e.g. Classic ASP, Windows Scripting Host, HTML Application (via IE)).  This snippet of code will create an object "App" with a "Path" property.  If you stick this in your script you can simply use "App.Path" in your code similarly as you would in VB6. ("Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life.")

Answer (score 5):

Your line

```
Directory = CurrentDirectory\attribute.exe
```

does not match any feature I have encountered in a vbscript instruction manual.
The following works for me, tho not sure what/where you expect "attribute.exe" to reside.

```
dim fso
dim curDir
dim WinScriptHost
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run curDir & "\testme.bat", 1
set WinScriptHost = nothing
```

Comment: for that line `Directory = CurrentDirectory\attribute.exe` i was trying to set a variable. i guess that it doesnt work. as for this code `WinScriptHost.Run curDir & "\testme.bat", 1` i need it to still do its job and run my batch application file without the command window.

Answer (score 2):

simple:

```
scriptdir = replace(WScript.ScriptFullName,WScript.ScriptName,"")
```

Comment: current directory <> directory of script; dupl of at least two 'use ScriptFullName'-answers; worst practice: Replace instead of .GetParentFolderName().

Answer (score 2):

Use [With](https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/vbscript-systems-administrator/vbscript-statements-explanation-of-the-with-end-with-statement/) in the code.

Try this way :

```
''''Way 1

currentdir=Left(WScript.ScriptFullName,InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName,"\"))


''''Way 2

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CurrentPath=.CurrentDirectory
End With


''''Way 3

With WSH
CD=Replace(.ScriptFullName,.ScriptName,"")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 simplest ways:

1. `Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")`
2. `Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
wscript.echo Mid(WScript.ScriptFullName,1,InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
```