# GetAbsolutePathName not return expected path

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a VBA macro in a Word document.  In this macro, I need to capture the directory in which the Word document itself is located.  Using this code:

```
Dim fso
Dim curDir
Dim WinScriptHost
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

The Word document is located in 'c:\users\myname\Documents\Projects\Project_1\project_scripts'.  But what I get back in curDir is simply 'c:\users\myname\Documents'.

I've read through [getting current directory in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138831/getting-current-directory-in-vbscript) several times, but the fix is escaping me.

Comment: Try `thisdocument.Path`

Comment: Your code works fine on my end if I run it from word doc module.

Comment: vba or vbscript?

Comment: RE: 'thisdocument.Path' -- exactly where/how to try it? RE: 'runi it from word doc module' -- I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.  RE: vba or vbscript -- I'm not clear on the difference. You tell me. I open the Word doc, open 'developer', open and edit macro.  I'm much more a shell script guy.

Comment: `curDir = thisdocument.Path`

Comment: @EdStevens That's VBA - not VBScript. The two are not the same :). Anyways, just declare curDir as a string with `Dim curDir as String`, then on the next line write `curDir = ThisWorkbook.Path`.

Comment: @dwirony -  two lines.  First line:  'Dim curDir As String'  Second line: 'curDir = ThisWorkbook.Path'.  Second line returns 'runtime error 414 - object required'

Comment: @EdStevens Sorry sorry my bad,`ThisDocument` - not workbook.

Comment: @dwirony - same result.  Meanwhile, I continued to google, found an example for excel and figured that 'ActiveWorksheet' should be 'ActiveDocument' for word.  First line: 'Dim folderPath As String'  Second line 'folderPath = Application.ActiveDocument.Path'.  That got me the result I want.  Thanks to everyone for the leads.

Comment: @EdStevens Ah - suppose it depends on whether or not the document is saved or not. But glad you found your solution!