# Regwrite nonpersistent value in the registry after restart

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I have this script (below), not the best script but it works fine, however every time I restart my computer that new registry triplet is gone and I have no guess why.

I got no errors from this script, but if I let it run for a reasonably period of time a `vbs Msgbox`pops up with,

> This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your antivirus software.

I honestly don't think it is related but apparently I cannot post a question being concise due to text requirements limitations. Or is it related and the antivirus is wiping out that triplet? After this message the new register is still there (in the registry) but not after a restart.

```
Dim sKey
sKey = "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\so_Robocopy"
Dim fso 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If fso.FileExists("so_Robocopy.bat") Then

    RegisterOnWindowsStartUp()
    MsgBox "Backup message text"
    
    Do While True
        wshShell.Run Chr(34) & "so_Robocopy.bat" & Chr(34), 0
        WScript.Sleep 300000
    Loop
Else 

    RemoveFromRegistry()

End If

Function RemoveFromRegistry()
    On Error Resume Next 
    wshShell.RegDelete sKey 'Error handling routine
End Function

Function RegisterOnWindowsStartUp()

    If DoesRegistryExist = False Then
        wshShell.RegWrite sKey, Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34), "REG_SZ"
    End If

End Function

Function DoesRegistryExist()

    with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        on error resume next
            sValue = .regread(sKey)
            DoesRegistryExist = (err.number = 0)
        on error goto 0
    End with

End Function
```

Comment: Is [this you as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65462310/692942)? Same script different problem, different user asking.

Comment: @Lankymart No, is not me, however this unexpected behaviour arouse as a consequence of that script

Comment: That’s a heck of a coincidence, same script asked couple of days apart both active this evening, not to mention you also happen to answer that question then ask a question yourself about the same script?

Comment: @Lankymart same functionality however at closer look we see that is not the same script. And honestly I just found this question today. I think I see your point... No, I am not farming rep.

Comment: Because your condition is failing when checking for `so_Robocopy.bat` and this function `RemoveFromRegistry()` is being called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you run the script, it will work fine, and no problem because you are running the script on the current directory and the `so_Robocopy.bat` existed on the same directory.

However, on Windows Startup, the script will execute on the Directory of Windows Startup and not on the original directory where your script is located.

Here's what happened to your code,

```
' Script execute from the Directory of Windows Starup
If fso.FileExists("so_Robocopy.bat") Then ' (1) There will be no so_Robocopy.bat on the Directory of Windows Startup, then this will return false.

    RegisterOnWindowsStartUp()
    MsgBox "Backup message text"
    
    Do While True
        wshShell.Run Chr(34) & "so_Robocopy.bat" & Chr(34), 0
        WScript.Sleep 300000
    Loop
Else (2) The condition is false, then remove the key from registry.
    RemoveFromRegistry()
End If
```

Make sure you are looking from the original directory where your script is. You can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `WScript.ScriptFullName` for that.

```
(1)
so_robocopy_file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\so_Robocopy.bat" 

If fso.FileExists(so_robocopy_file) Then ' (2)

    RegisterOnWindowsStartUp()
    MsgBox "Backup message text"
    
    Do While True
        wshShell.Run Chr(34) & so_robocopy_file & Chr(34), 0 ' (3)
        WScript.Sleep 300000
    Loop
Else
```