# How to fix this error on running a vbs script with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vbscript

The VBScript I want to run through Python with Wscript.exe is a looping one type (when you press OK, it will pop up again). It is located in a folder called "extras", let's say on the Desktop folder. It CAN open the file with Wscript, but pressing OK won't work (causes an error). The Python script works, but the VBScript doesn't. I am very confused what causes the error (Error code: 80070002, cannot find file). Running it without Python works fine. Below is my Python code:

```py
import os, subprocess

workingdir = os.getcwd()
programname = "wscript.exe"
filename = "runme.vbs"
fileloc = f"{workingdir}\extras\{filename}"

print(fileloc)
subprocess.Popen([programname, fileloc])
```

And maybe if you need the VBScript (named runme.vbs) code:

```vb
X = MsgBox("Hello world!", 64)
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "runme.vbs" 
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "runme.vbs"
```

Comment: Well, where are you running this from? Apparently your current working directory doesn't have `extras` or doesn't have the file inside extras...

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. There is a folder named "extras" with the vbscript inside. (in the current working dir)

Comment: @TheStupidDev hope this question helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16138831)