# run a vbscript from usb "AS ADMIN" and get drive letter to ru batch script stored in usb drive

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have following vbscript:

```
set objShell = Createobject("wscript.shell")
objShell.Run """Scripts\Rec.bat""", 0
objShell.Run """Scripts\Prod.bat""", 0
Set objShell = Nothing
```

The above vbscript is stored in USB drive and i am trying to launch it from usb.
Now problem is when i normally run this vbscript it executes. But when i do run as administrator from context menu following error occurs "System cannot find the file specified"

I tried to debug the problem using another below script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strPath = objShell.CurrentDirectory
strDrive = objFSO.GetDriveName(strPath)
Wscript.Echo strDrive
```

When i run it normally it echo F: that is my usb drive letter.
But when i run as admin it echo C:

So the batch file location is being searced to C:\Scripts\Rec.bat instead of F:\Scripts\Rec.bat thats why this error is comming.

Can anyone help??

I want to run vbscript as admin and still retain the usb drive letter path because the code in my Rec.bat requires admin privilege

Comment: Because you're running in the context of the Administrator user, not yourself.

Comment: I know thats the problem. i want to run vbscript as admin and still retain the usb drive letter path

Comment: Try using the script's directory instead of current directory. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043076/15764378).

Comment: @TathastuPandya Look at the duplicate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225466/692942) explains it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't want it to be relative to the current directory, you want it to be relative to the directory of the running vbscript:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
strPath = "" & strFolder & "\Scripts\Rec.bat" & ""

objShell.Run strPath, 0
```

*If you want to try it with a test script, you'd be advised to replace `0` on the last line with `1`.*

Comment: Thanks seems to be working but what if i have to run muliple more than one batch scripts. i am no expert at vbscript. can you help with that using some loop or alike pleaseee

Comment: Exactly as the first duplicate explains - "You can use WScript.ScriptFullName which will return the full path of the executing script."