# File not found when ExecuteGlobal after a ReadAll in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

this might be trivial but I'm writing a VBScript template and I wanted to add the possibility to inject VBScript code from the internet inside VBScript and run it.

The code originally was:

```
Sub WebImport(URL)
    ' Import the VBS code at a given URL.
    ' and run it globally pushing the functions into the Main
    Dim Request    
    Set Request = createobject ("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Request.Open "GET", URL, false
    Request.Send
    ExecuteGlobal Request.ResponseText
    Set Request = Nothing
End Sub
```

I already wrote a function to import code, just like Python, and the principle is the same. It works flawlessly.

If the `WebImport` works as it should, I'll create a basic import that handles them in the same way.

I import the raw code from my own repository [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FabioFlorey/I-Heart-VBScript).

It does everything correctly except executing the file globally in the Main scope, I tried with/without deleting the file, the result doesn't change at all, unfortunately...

##### Edit

This is the full script, it imports `WebImport` from `scr/Functions` and runs the code to inject the code from a given repo until it has to write a file, then `800a0046 vbscript at row 0, line 1` kicks in... I'm admin on the machine.

```vb
Option Explicit

'                                 VBScript Main File Model
' Author:                            
'      Fabio Craig Wimmer Florey (fabioflorey@hackermail.com)
'
' Reviewed By:                                                  Last Review:
'      Fabio Craig Wimmer Florey (fabioflorey@hackermail.com)     2022-03-29
'
' Description:
'      Main Subroutine


Import "src/Functions"
WebImport "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmoosaJHB/Docker-compose-SuiteCRM/714bada98abbb2ab497258c8ea9a726f234aaba3/public_html/vendor/gymadarasz/ace/demo/kitchen-sink/docs/vbscript.vbs"

Sub Main()
  ' Main Subroutine
  MakeHelloWorldFile "Hello.txt"
End Sub

Sub Import(Filename)
  '    Import Code from VBS File, DO NOT DELETE
    Dim Lib, Code, FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Lib = FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename & ".vbs")
    Code = Lib.ReadAll
    Lib.Close
    ExecuteGlobal Code
    Set Lib = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub

Call Main
```

Comment: Why write out `TextResponse` to a file when you could execute it directly from `Request.responsetext`?

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried to execute the `TextResponse` and it didn't work, so I placed it on there to see if the script could read and write the file. VBScript still responded file not found, so I decided to write to check wheter it was possibile to execute the code that way. I just added the old version! :)

Comment: Does your `Import` method work with a file saved from the URL you're trying to include?

Comment: I update the body with more info @TimWilliams

Comment: Are you trying to solve a `File not found` error, as stated in the question title, or a `Permission denied` (800A0046) error as stated in the "Edit"? For the `File not found` error, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043076/15764378) to force the script's directory to be the current directory.

Comment: If there is a problem with the XHR response trying to output it to file isn’t going to help. You need to diagnose what is causing `ResponseText` to fail. Would start by [checking the `Request.Status`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208913/692942), if you are not receiving a HTTP 200 range response you will not be receiving the expected text.

Comment: The problem is your `Import()` procedure, the `FileSystemObject` does not support passing a relative path to the `OpenTextFile()` method, you need to pass a complete path. See [Open Relative path in VBS with OpenText and SaveAs method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25944232). Adding the line below your `FSO` declaration in `Import()` will fix the code `Dim path: path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\"` you then change the `OpenTextFile()` line to `Set Lib = FSO.OpenTextFile(path & Filename & ".vbs")` and it will call your `WebImport()` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the XHR call that works without needing to try outputting the response to a file. The issue is the `FileSystemObject` does not support relative paths you need to [provide the relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25944232/692942) using code like;

```vb
Dim path: path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\"
```

With the following changes to the `Import()` procedure the code will run `WebImports()` from the `src\Functions.vbs` file.

```vb
'Use the correct directory separator
Import "src\Functions"

'... other code excluded for clarity

Sub Import(Filename)
  '    Import Code from VBS File, DO NOT DELETE
    Dim Lib, Code, FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get path based off the script
    Dim path: path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\"
    'Append path to the filename
    Set Lib = FSO.OpenTextFile(path & Filename & ".vbs")
    Code = Lib.ReadAll
    Lib.Close
    ExecuteGlobal Code
    Set Lib = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```