# Create a relative path to the file txt

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript that reads and records in txt file after pressing the button:

```
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Licznik_ID = myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Etykieta_NC\Counter\Counter.txt").ReadAll
Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1
myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Etykieta_NC\Counter\Counter.txt",2,True).Write(Licznik_ID)
```

I would like to create a relative path to the file

```
"C:\Etykieta_NC\Counter\Counter.txt"
```

to

```
"C:\Etykieta_NC\Form"
```

How to do it in VBScript?

Comment: to "C:\Etykieta_NC\Form"

Comment: But relative to what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBscript relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15621395/692942)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant parts of your filesystem structure look like this:

```
C:\
└─Etykieta_NC
  ├─Counter
  │ └─Counter.txt
  └─Form
```

Assuming that you want to create a relative path *from* the `Form` subfolder (not to it) the path would go one directory up (`..`) and then down the `Counter` subtree:

```
..\Counter\Counter.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GetAbsolutePathName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx1xa64f(v=vs.84).aspx) to build your relative path, here's a quick example

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim items: items = Array("c:", "c:\test", "c:test", "c:..\Counter")
Dim item, path
For Each item In items
  path = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(item)
  WScript.Echo "Test: PathSpec = " & item & ", Result = " & path
Next
```