# how to get the directory of the vbscript file in the script

Tags: vbscript

I want to store the address of my test.vbs file within the script itself.
Is there a way to find it?

I can't find it on the internet.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15621612/603855

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner you have the ability to close flag as a duplicate so why not do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBscript relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621395/vbscript-relative-path)

Answer (score -2):

Try Dir("test.vbs") or App.Path. It should return your app's filepath.

Comment: That's not VBScript.

Comment: You're right. Its actually a VB6 function. To return the directory, you can use the WShell's File System Objects. e.g. Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). There are a number of useful fso functions like fso.GetFolder(filename) or fso.FolderExists(file), the latter is similar to the VB6 Dir(file) function which I mentioned.