# Error using VBScript in BGInfo File not found error

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm an amateur VB scripter.

I am creating a script to output the ID.
The file contains the line "ad.annnet.id = 564654068". It is necessary to output "ID: 564654068"

```
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\nID=(\d+)"
    Echo .Execute(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("this.conf").ReadAll)(0).Submatches(0)
End With
```

Comment: If the file contains `ad.annnet.id = 564654068` the pattern you have set in the `RegExp` is wrong. Also, the question title seems to have no relevance to the question?

Comment: You can't pass a relative path in `OpenTextFile()` it has to be absolute which you can get by passing it into the [`GetAbsolutePathName()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/zx1xa64f(v=vs.84)), see [VBscript relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15621773).

Comment: @user692942 , could you help correct the my code and show how it might look from your point of view, please? I would be very grateful to you

Comment: The link, provided in my previous comment should help. You can [edit] the question with what you've tried and we will go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bginfo, click **Custom**, **New**, enter **ID** for the identifier, Check the **VB Script file** radio button, and then click **Browse** to select a VBScript file you have saved with the code below. Then add the "ID" item to the bginfo display area. Note: The "file not found" error is resolved by using the AppData environment variable to reference the AnyDesk data file.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
AppData = oWSH.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")
DataFile = AppData & "\AnyDesk\system.conf"
Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(DataFile,ForReading)
Do Until oFile.AtEndOfStream
  Line = oFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(Line,"ad.anynet.id") Then ID = Split(Line,"=")(1)
Loop
oFile.Close
Echo ID
```

Please note that the data is returned to bginfo via one or more **Echo** statements. If testing this script outside of bginfo, change **Echo** to **WScript.Echo**.

Comment: Not a fan of magic numbers please define constants properly, in this case use `Const ForReading = 1` and `oFSO.OpenTextFile(DataFile, ForReading)` (even though it's the default).

Comment: Has anyone ever managed to do something like this? Please show me a working example

Comment: Are you asking abut extracting the ID from the line "ad.annnet.id = 564654068"? That's a trivial addition of one line using **Split**. No need for regexp at all. I have updated the answer accordingly. If I've misunderstood, please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @sogohimo The question was about the error `File Not Found` if you are having issues with parsing the value from the file, ask a different question. But please, be clear descriptive and show what you have tried.

Comment: @user692942 I have a remote access program installed. I need to display the user ID in bginfo.
I'm don't know much about vbs, so I turned to stackoverflow. 
The system file is located along the path: C: \ Users \ sogohimo \ AppData \ Roaming \ AnyDesk  \ system.conf 
File contents: 
ad.ancl.cached_config=
ad.anynet.alias=
ad.anynet.client_stats_hash=
ad.anynet.cur_version=
ad.anynet.fpr=
ad.anynet.id=303314931 
ad.anynet.last_relay=
ad.anynet.network_hash=
ad.anynet.network_id=main
ad.anynet.relay.fatal_result=1.0
ad.anynet.relay.state=0

I need to display "303314931"

Comment: If you could help, could you send a letter to the post office? sogohimo@icloud.com

Comment: With bginfo, you can define new fields via a script, as described here https://www.verboon.info/2012/02/how-to-use-vbscripts-in-bginfo/ and you can also directly edit the bginfo configuration file via a script, since it's just a text file. Now that I have a better idea about what you're trying to, I'll edit my reply with something closer to what you're requesting.

Comment: @sogohimo Did this answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the script, the actual cause of the "File not found" error is as [@craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17429064/craig-covey) pointed out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69991051/692942) the `FileSystemObject` can't locate the file "this.conf". This is because the `OpenTextFile()` method doesn't support relative paths and expects an absolute path to the file whether it is in the same directory as the executing script or not.

You can fix this by calling [`GetAbsolutePathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/zx1xa64f(v=vs.84)) and passing in the filename.

> <sup>From [Official Documentation - GetAbsolutePathName Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/zx1xa64f(v=vs.84))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Assuming the current directory is c:\mydocuments\reports, the following table illustrates the behaviour of the `GetAbsolutePathName` method.
>
> | pathspec (JScript) | pathspec (VBScript) | Returned path |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | "c:" | "c:" | "c:\mydocuments\reports" |
> | "c:.." | "c:.." | "c:\mydocuments" |
> | "c:\" | "c:" | "c:" |
> | "c:*.*\may97" | "c:*.*\may97" | "c:\mydocuments\reports*.*\may97" |
> | "region1" | "region1" | "c:\mydocuments\reports\region1" |
> | "c:\..\..\mydocuments" | "c:....\mydocuments" | "c:\mydocuments" |

Something like this should work;

```
'Read the file from the current directory (can be different from the directory executing the script, check the execution).
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim filename: filename = "this.conf"
Dim filepath: filepath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(filename)
Dim filecontent: filecontent = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath).ReadAll
```

Update: [It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984855/error-using-vbscript-in-bginfo-file-not-found-error/70003788?noredirect=1#comment123758428_70003788) you can use path modifiers in `OpenTextFile()` after all (thank you @LesFerch), so this should also work;

```
'Read the file from the current directory (can be different from the directory executing the script, check the execution).
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim filename: filename = ".\this.conf" '.\ denotes the current directory
Dim filecontent: filecontent = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
```

Another issue is the current `RegExp` pattern will not match what you are expecting, would recommend using something like [Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions first.

Comment: I use relative paths with OpenTextFile() all the time. I just ensure that the current directory is set to the script directory and precede the filename with ".\".

Comment: @LesFerch in that case leave an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15621395/692942) so others can benefit from your wisdom. I haven't tested it myself and the documentation makes no reference to relative path usage, seems strange that if it supports it why include a method called `GetAbsolutePathName()` in the `FileSystemObject` in the first place? In any case, you're still specifying a path modifier so it's along a similar line. In fact, it probably uses `GetAbsolutePathName()` in `OpenTextFile()`.

Comment: @LesFerch suggested leaving an answer on [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15621395/692942) about relative paths, would have been better served there instead of [posting here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013922/692942).

Comment: I posted that answer as requested and posted a new answer here which I think (hope) is more along the lines of what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You will never get the value/display that you're looking for if the output is

> File Not Found

The regexp is meaningless until the path to the file is specified.  As it stands, the "this.conf" file must be in the same location as the script itself - and from the error, I'm assuming that's not the case.

Comment: you are wrong. File in the same folder with VBS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @sogohimo Craig is right, they just don't explain themselves very well.