# Why is my readall function popping up a error?

Tags: vbscript

Im trying to read my file in vbs and put it in a variable, but I keep getting a error stating that my input is in past the end of the file, and I don't know why..

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("holder.canz", ForReading)
strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close
WScript.Echo strText
```

Comment: Try to use the complete path of the file.

Comment: I tried that first and I did ./holder.canz to

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043076/15764378) for using a relative path. However, `input is past the end of the file` instead of `file not found` suggests a different problem. Try a different test file. Maybe there is something unusual about `holder.canz`. The file is probably empty.

Comment: @VBasic2008 This isn't a `file not found` issue. The problem is with the input file. It's either empty or appears empty to the file system object (maybe starts with a ctrl-z). The duplicate link should cover it.